# Using a CGFloat value from ViewController to move a view in TabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm so close to just throw my laptop away. For 3 days, again, 3 days I'm looking for this specific piece of code and I cannot seem to find out how. My project became a whole commented-out-code graveyard. I would give anything for an answer. Please help me.

**What I want:** My `ViewController` has a `gestureRecognizer` that gets me the value eg. `var fingerPos` of the current finger position. Simple example:

```
 @objc func panGestureRecognizerHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        fingerPos = sender.location(in: view?.window)
}
```

I want to get the `fingerPos` position and pass it to the `TabBarController`. That value should then be used to move the `TabBarController`. For example `self.view.frame.origin.y = fingerPos.y`. The movement/update of the value must be continuous.

**What I tried:** `NSNotificationCenter`, `didSet`,`Structs` in combination with `didSet`, Various types of function passing eg.

```
//Function in ViewController

func IBegYouGiveMeTheValueFunction() -> CGFloat {
 return fingerPos
}


//In the TabBarController

let vc = ViewController()
self.view.frame.origin.y = vc.IBegYouGiveMeTheValueFunction()
```

that resulted in crashes because the "Value was found nil" even though it had a value, Adding the `TabBarController` as a child which resulted in a white screen on the simulator and fan spinning, Values written out of any classes (public), Trying to set the position of the `TabBarController` in the `ViewController`, literally anything I found online.

Can anyone help me with this? I would be really thankful!

Comment: Is this ViewController sitting in a tab of the TabBarController?

Comment: @RohanBhale Yes, The ViewController is one item in the TabBarController. I basically have the TabBarController as the initial one.

Comment: The method sender.location(in: view?.window) returns a CGPoint. So fingerPos is essentially a CGPoint and not a CGFloat. You are returning fingerPos from IBegYouGiveMeTheValueFunction() which should return a CGFloat, but instead you return a CGPoint. Is your code even compiling? Please correct the typo in your question.

Comment: Also have you checked the documentation for location(in:) of the UIGestureRecognizer. The view parameter should be the view on which the gesture took place. If you want the location on the window pass this parameter as nil. Dont pass the window object here instead pass a nil

Comment: @RohanBhale Hey man. Sorry, I explained it wrong. What I basically want is I want to get a value from one VC to another VC and there it should change something continuously. Eg. a slider on VC1 that moves a view on VC2. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to inform the TabBarController that there is a new value?

Comment: @RohanBhale I tried `didSet` and it printed the value but it didn't move anything. I also tried to pass the value into a label and the label just stays empty even though when I print the `label.text` it also shows me that the label has the value but it simply doesn't change the actual label.

Comment: Please add the implementation of what you do in the didSet

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a custom TabBarController class.

The view controllers in each tab can be accessed via the tab bar controllers `.viewControllers` array, so you can call funds or set properties directly.

- In your first tab view controller, track the finger position with the drag gesture.
- When it changes, get a reference to the view controller in the second tab.
- Call a func in that vc, which will, for example, update the position of a subView.

Here is a complete, simple example. Just add a `UITabBarController` to a Storyboard, and assign the class of the two default tab controllers to `MyFirstViewController` and `MySecondViewController` included in the following code (you don't need to add anything else... no `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` needed):

```
class MyFirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let statusLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.textColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "Tracking" + "\n\n" + "Drag your finger in view..."
        return v
    }()

    var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(statusLabel)

        topConstraint = statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topConstraint,
            statusLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            statusLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
        ])

        let pg = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerHandler(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pg)

    }

    @objc func panGestureRecognizerHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let fingerPos = sender.location(in: view)
        var strTmp = "Tracking Y: \(fingerPos.y)"
        topConstraint.constant = fingerPos.y

        guard let tb = self.tabBarController else {
            strTmp += "\n\n" + "Must be in a tabBarController!"
            statusLabel.text = strTmp
            return
        }

        guard let vControllers = tb.viewControllers else {
            strTmp += "\n\n" + "Could not get viewControllers from tabBarController!"
            statusLabel.text = strTmp
            return
        }

        guard vControllers.count > 1, let secondVC = vControllers[1] as? MySecondViewController else {
            strTmp += "\n\n" + "VC in second tab is not MySecondViewController!"
            statusLabel.text = strTmp
            return
        }

        // in case we have not yet navigated to the second tab
        secondVC.loadViewIfNeeded()

        // tell SecondVC to update the Y position
        secondVC.updateYPosition(at: fingerPos.y)

        strTmp += "\n\n" + "Sent!"

        statusLabel.text = strTmp

    }

}

class MySecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let statusLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.textColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "Have not received" + "\n\n" + "a Y update yet..."
        return v
    }()

    var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(statusLabel)

        topConstraint = statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topConstraint,
            statusLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            statusLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
        ])

    }

    func updateYPosition(at y: CGFloat) -> Void {
        topConstraint.constant = y
        statusLabel.text = "Top contstraint constant:" + "\n\n" + "\(y)"
    }

}
```

When you run this, the first thing you see is the first tab:

[image]

As you tap-and-drag your finger, the top of the red label will follow:

[image]

When you select the second tab, you will see a blue label with its top at the same Y position where you dragged the red label:

[image]

Comment: A little late but I wanted to thank you so much for your answer. That helped me to solve my problem!